# Kali linux throws ' isolinux.bin missing or corrupt ' error

Tags: linux, command-line, boot, live-usb, kali-linux

I downloaded Kali Linux from this [link](http://www.kali.org/), I have a 32 bit OS, so I guessed ISO 32 Kali Linux is the suitable for me  (they did not clarify in the website based on what we choose the type).
Then, I installed Kali Linux on USB using 32 image writer.
After that I changed the booting setting to boot from USB and this message appears:

> isolinux.bin missing  or corrupt

and  Kali Linux did not launch .

I found in the [link suggested solution to solve the problem](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18246-Live-usb-throws-isolinux-bin-missing-error) but because I did not deal with file system before I did not know how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was because the downloading was not complete, Although Chrome showed that it is complete
 
I re-downloaded from another browser and it work fine now.